# DependencyProperty not working on custom UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

I have some simple Dependency Properties that are not working.  I've looked over them, looked over code I've used in the past, and I'm not sure why they are not working.

I have a custom base class (MyBaseControl) that extends UserControl, and my custom UI controls then extend on that.  For example, MyCustomControl extends MyBaseControl.

MyCustomControl XAML is simple enough:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Blurb}" />
</StackPanel>
```

MyCustomControl Code looks like this:

```
public partial class MyCustomControl: MyBaseControl
{
    //public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty = Image.SourceProperty.AddOwner(typeof(MyCustomControl));
    //public static readonly DependencyProperty BlurbProperty = TextBlock.TextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(MyCustomControl));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Icon",
        typeof(ImageSource),
        typeof(MyCustomControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BlurbProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Blurb",
        typeof(String),
        typeof(MyCustomControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MyCustomControl() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region Properties

    public ImageSource Icon
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }

    public String Blurb
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(BlurbProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BlurbProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion Properties
}
```

Notice that I've tried a few different ways to define the `DependencyProperty`.  Neither works.

I call my control in the following way:

```
<ctrl:MyCustomControl Height="240" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="320" Blurb="Slide Show" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Resources/photo_scenery.png" />
```

If I set the Source or Text directly in the XAML, they show up just fine.  The bindings are just not wanting to work properly.

What am I missing that is not allowing my bindings to pass through?

Thank you for any help!

**UPDATE:** I've updated the code based on comments and additional changes I've tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are registering Icon property incorrectly. In its registration method you need to specify the DP name i.e. in place of "`IconProperty`" it should be "`Icon`" -

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Icon",
        typeof(ImageSource),
        typeof(MyCustomControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Also, try setting RelativeSource in your bindings like this -

```
<StackPanel>
    <Image Source="{Binding Icon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
            Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ctrl:MyCustomControl}}}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Blurb, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
            Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ctrl:MyCustomControl}}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks RV1987.  I was so ready to shake my fist in the air for missing that, but it looks like I have at least 2 problems with my code.  I made the above change, but am still not seeing my image.

Comment: I have updated the answer. You need to specify the relativeSource for your bindings.

Comment: The RelativeSource on the bindings did it.  Thank you!  I'm going to need to read up again on what all that is doing -- as I'm not understanding the need for them, but it works for now!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, instead of setting RelativeSource as suggested by Rohit Vats, you may be able to solve the issue by updating your code as follows

```
<StackPanel>
    <Image Name="imgImage" Source="{Binding Icon}" />
    <TextBlock Name="txtTextBlock" Text="{Binding Blurb}" />
</StackPanel>
```

and

```
public LabeledTextBox()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    imgImage.DataContext = this;
    txtTextBlock.DataContext = this;
}
```